# How can I connect two Ubuntu VMs so that I can log in with the same user on both of them?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, user-profiles

I'm not sure as to how I have to approach the task since I can't find any explanation to it on the internet. Both VMs are running with Ubuntu ver. 18.04 and I'm using Virtualbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The technology you are looking for is called LDAP. One system is the LDAP server and all other systems can join the LDAP domain as LDAP clients, or domain members.

Here is some information to get you started:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html.en